# MVC4 / JS / AJAX : Html.Raw output displacing content from a href tags in view HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

There is a feature in my project where emails sent to a certain address get parsed with attachments being saved to network and meta data saved to a database.  When details on a finished good are loaded, that has a serial number that matches the serial included in the parsed email, the project generates a note associated with the serial and generates note text with links to the file attachments saved on the network.  The purpose of this is that images and PDFs of finished goods in the field can be sent to us by technicians and then automatically uploaded and accessible through an attached note in our web portal.

The problem I'm running into is that after the note is generated, when the details of the note are viewed, the HTML has the link content text moved outside of the  tags so the link content/string is displayed but not clickable.  The text in the database for the note has the link text wrapped in  tags that link to the file.

The note details are loaded as a partial view inside of a modal pop up window.

I can't figure out how or why the databased note text is being rearranged when displaying in a view using Html.Raw.

The Modal Partial View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TeamPortal.Models.SpaNoteDetailsModel>" %>

<div class="box" style="padding:6px;">
        <br /><br />
        <div id="SpaNoteDetailContainer">
            <div class="SpaNoteInfo"> <%: string.Format("Last modified on {0} by {1}", Model.SpaNote.ModifiedDate ?? Model.SpaNote.CreatedDate, Model.SpaNote.ModifiedBy ?? Model.SpaNote.CreatedBy)%></div>
            <hr />
            <%: Html.Raw(Model.SpaNote.SpaNoteText)%>
        </div>
</div>
```

The JS AJAX call to load view into modal:

```
    var detailsSpaNoteSetup = function () {
    $(selectors.detailsSpaNoteLink).live('click', function () {

        var spaNoteId = $(this).attr(attributes.spaNoteId);

        $(selectors.dialog).attr(attributes.title, 'Spa Note Details');

        $.ajax({
            url: inputs.detailsUrl,
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                spaNoteId: spaNoteId
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $(selectors.dialog).html(result.toString());
                $(selectors.dialog).dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 450,
                    width: 600,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Mainly I'd like to stop this behavior with understanding why it happens as a bonus.  Let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks.

Additional information requested:
SpaNote property of Model is a table object of the table holding the spa notes in the project.  SpaNoteText is a column of the spa note table containing the content for the spa note (datatype of nvarchar(MAX)).

Example spa note text in database:

```
[Note content containing personal information]<hr /><a href="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/large_351111100012-IMG_1018_20140305141439.JPG" target="_blank" /><img src="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/norml_351111100012-IMG_1018_20140305141439.JPG" /></a><br /><a href="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/large_351111100012-IMG_1025_20140305141439.JPG" target="_blank" /><img src="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/norml_351111100012-IMG_1025_20140305141439.JPG" /></a><br /><a href="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/large_351111100012-IMG_1026_20140305141439.JPG" target="_blank" /><img src="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/norml_351111100012-IMG_1026_20140305141439.JPG" /></a><br /><a href="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/large_351111100012-IMG_1027_20140305141439.JPG" target="_blank" /><img src="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/norml_351111100012-IMG_1027_20140305141439.JPG" /></a><br />
```

HTML of view loading note text from database above:

```
[Note content containing personal information]<hr><a href="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/large_351111100012-IMG_1018_20140305141439.JPG" target="_blank"></a><img src="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/norml_351111100012-IMG_1018_20140305141439.JPG"><br><a href="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/large_351111100012-IMG_1025_20140305141439.JPG" target="_blank"></a><img src="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/norml_351111100012-IMG_1025_20140305141439.JPG"><br><a href="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/large_351111100012-IMG_1026_20140305141439.JPG" target="_blank"></a><img src="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/norml_351111100012-IMG_1026_20140305141439.JPG"><br><a href="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/large_351111100012-IMG_1027_20140305141439.JPG" target="_blank"></a><img src="https://assets.maaxspas.com/ShowUsImages/norml_351111100012-IMG_1027_20140305141439.JPG"><br>
```

Let me know if more is needed, thanks.

Comment: Could you also post the content of `Model.SpaNote.SpaNoteText` ?

Comment: Model.SpaNote.SpaNoteText explained and spa note database and in view example added.

Comment: Your anchor tags are auto-closing. They seem to be wrapping an `img` and then closed again. This additional `</a>` might interfere with the interpretation of the `HTML` content and generate unexpected behavior.

Comment: Well that's... embarrassing.  Poured over my code a hundred times and never noticed I auto closed my a tags.  No idea why I would do that, I'm guessing I was already auto closing the img tags and just did it for all of them without thinking.  Thank you very much Yan.  If you want, go ahead and submit this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anchor tags are auto-closing. They seem to be wrapping an `img` and then closed again. This additional `</a>` might interfere with the interpretation of the HTML content and generate unexpected behavior